# Get Attribute Value by LINQ

Tags: linq, html-agility-pack, getelementbyid

The HTML Source is as follows

```
<img id="itemImage" src="https://www.xyz.com/item1.jpg">
```

I am using the following LINQ query to get the SRC value (Image Link)

```
string imageURL = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                    .Where(node => node.Attributes["id"] != null && node.Attributes["id"].Value == "itemImage")
                    .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value).ToString();
```

But the imageURL gives output as

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode,System.String]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is casting it to string. `Select()` returns `IEnumerable<T>` so you are basically converting an enumerator to a string (as the error message says). Call `First()` or `Single()` or `Take(1)` in order to get a single element before casting it to a string.

```
.Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value).First().ToString();
```

Also, if there is a chance that the desired element is not present, `FirstOrDefault()` and `SingleOrDefault()` returns null rather then throwing an exception. In that case, I would recommend

```
var imageUlr = ... .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value).FirstOrDefault();
if (imageUrl != null)
{
    // cast it to string and do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
    .FirstOrDefault

```
string imageURL = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                .Where(node => node.Attributes["id"] != null && node.Attributes["id"].Value == "itemImage")
                .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
string imageURL = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                .Where(node => node.Attributes["id"] != null && node.Attributes["id"].Value == "itemImage")
                .Select(node => node.Attributes["src"].Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```